# Tracking user activity for illegal usage

Tags: reporting

I have a user in SFDC who has probably downloaded some of our SFDC data illegally on unauthorized computer. Any way to see what user visited, downloaded in past?

Comment: you might want to use Files and Content Download reports https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_content.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Great one. Can I do this for a report too? Like if a user ran and downloaded the report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can request [Historical Event Logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212606&language=en_US&type=1) from Salesforce (At a substantial cost).

The upside? You can get exactly the data you are looking for, for a time period.

> As part of the Historical Event Logs service we will provide logs for either a specific User, Record or Organization and will cover the following logged Event record types:
>
> - Login along with Source IP, URI and the time stamp (GMT)
> - Pages accessed via the user interface (This includes Visualforce pages)
> - Viewed and run reports
> - Exported Reports (When a user clicks on “Export Details”)
> - Global searches

The downside? Its really expensive.

> For logs related to a User:
>
> From January 2014 – Present: USD $500 for data per week or 7 continuous days per user
>
> Example: total charge = USD $500 ( $500= for each week requested  x 1 user)
>
> For logs related to a specific record:
>
> From January 2014 – Present:  USD $500 for data per record per week or 7 continuous days
>
> Example: total charge = USD $500 ($500 = for each week requested x 1 record)
>
> For logs related to a specific Organization:
>
> From January 2014 – Present:  USD $500 for data per org per day with a max $7,500 for 1 month (Up to 31 continuous days)
>
> Example: total charge  = USD $3500 for 7 days ($500 = for each day requested x 1 org)
>                                       = USD $7,500 for 21 days ($500 = for each day up to 15 days with no added charge for each additional day)

Compared to being in the dark about what a compromised user is doing, the price tag is worth the peace of mind.

---

For reference, [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) describes the format of the files you pay for, and [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) describes how to use that data.